# Why the size of the image change while rotating using CSS transform

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-animate, transform

I have card flip effect

```
function flip(card, callback) {
    $.each(card, function(i, card) {
        card = $(card);
        card.find('img').css({
            //perspective: 400,
            rotateX: 0
        }).animate({
            rotateX: 90
        }, function() {
            var file = card.hasClass('back') ? front : back;
            $(this).attr('src', file).css('rotateX', 270).animate({
                rotateX: 360
            }, function() {
                $(this).css('rotateX', 0);
                card.toggleClass('back front');
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And when I flipping the card (change rotateX - it's jQuery css plugin) on click the size of the card is much smaller and then when animation is finish it's go back to prevoius size. It work fine if I don't change the url when flipping. Why is this happen? How can I fix it? Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGUkh/).

**UPDATE** It seams that this happen only in Google Chrome. In Firefox it work fine.

Comment: You mean the point at which new image is loaded and the card disappears for a split of a second? A preloader will fix that.

Comment: @MightyPork No the width is like a half of original size when rotateX is between 270 and 360 and then it change back to original size. It have nothing to do with preloading since I have this issue all the time not only of first flip.

Comment: Oh I see, chrome screwed it up..no idea for fix though :(